# Java 2D game does not work from menu ?

Tags: java

Well I've been developing a 2D java game for a while but I face with a strange problem and I'm stuck :/. So that I'm uploading my source code here.

It is an eclipse project, in this project I have included 2 main methods to clearly state the problem i have experienced:

1. In Menu class, starts the system from the menu and menu passes the frame to the game manager after pressing play game button
2. In GameManager class, starts the system by passing a frame to game manager directly.

My problem is that: when I start the system from Menu class and press play game button, rendering continues but system does not respond to any actions even if I had added listeners to canvas, but it works when I start the system from the main method which belongs to GameManager class. :/

Here is my source code: http://www.mediafire.com/?4d2v1jfizrgpaqp

Thanks

Comment: @VinayakGarg That's completely unjustified. I had a lot of fun writing a game/game engine with java. Please don't offer criticism, but instead advice on solutions.

Comment: I don't intend to criticize, i just shared my agony of trying game development in Java. But maybe I am biased as I mainly program in C++.

Comment: @StM : When i run your Menu Class's main method and if i press any button other then Play Game, then all are working fine, but if i Press Play Game Button, then it simply prints Play Game is Pressed and GUI closes itself. I had done a minor modification though in that main method. But your other class is giving me errors of every sort. Regards

Comment: @StM : You need to rectify some things in your code though, before proceeding, like using Even Dispatcher Threads. And another one like  while initializing ArrayList do like this ArrayList<String> sStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); (JDK 6 or previous) or ArrayList<String> sStrings = new ArrayList(); (JDK 7). Do let me know, what i got is the expected thing ? or something else is being expected.  Regards

Comment: @StM : [Link for EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)  Hope that might help more. Regards

Comment: @Vinayak Garg: Developing a 3D game in Java is **absolutely** the same as developing it in C++. The only difference is at how you call OpenGL methods.

Comment: @ProphesyAwaits i'm actually not familiar with EDT, and where should i use EDT btw ? i mean it is a simple gui program :/